# redis Error: Server closed the connection

Tags: php, connection, redis

I have 6 nodes in a redis cluster - 3 master and 3 slaves. All the nodes are running just fine except for one master and it's slave.

On this troublesome master, when i run the command (on either master or slave), i get the following error:

```
Error: Server closed the connection
```

There is nothing in the redis error logs following this error. The redis error logs shows that everything is running smooth and this articular error does is not included in the logs.

However, the predis error logs show this error:

```
Error while reading line from the server [tcp: //192.168.2.100: 6379]
```

What can be causing this problem?